# Issues with Event Source creation deploying lambda function using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to deploy a Lambda function using serverless framework. The lambda function is invoked based on a Kinesis event source. When I try to deploy the lambda, I get this following problem.

> CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping

Does it mean we don't have permission to create `EventSource` for the lambda function?

Comment: It would usually give you an explanation message somewhere. Is that the first thing that failed in the event list?

Comment: Yes. This is the first thing failed in the list.

Comment: That's unhelpful of it! I think we might need a minimal reproducible case I'm afraid, as there's very little information there as it stands.

Comment: Okay so the resource failed to create, what was the reason CloudFormation gave?